# Django model order by custom algorithm Using the difference between the current time and creation time

Tags: python, django

Django version 2.1.15
Python version 3.7.4

**Djngo settings.py**

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ko-kr'
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Seoul'
```

I am not familiar with English.I will write in English as hard as possible.

Django model order by custom algorithm Using the difference between the current time and creation time

my model is

**models.py**

```
class Review(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
   content = models.TextField()
   movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
   like_users=models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='like_reviews')
   created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

i want to 
Descending order_by (Count(like_users)/(current_time - created_at + 60)) Review model

(current_time-created_at) : I want to change the difference between two hours to minutes. (integer)

I tested these things.

```
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper,F,Value
from django.db.models.fields import DurationField,DateTimeField
def test(request):
    now = timezone.localtime()
    test = Review.objects.annotate(diff_time=(ExpressionWrapper(Value(now, DateTimeField()) - F('created_at'), output_field=DurationField()))).annotate(diff_value=F('diff_time')+60).values()
```

But failed.
How can I get the results I want?

I used a translator to ask questions, but I hope my intentions are clearly communicated.
I'm so sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Welcome to SatckOverflow and don't worry too much about your English, just try your best. As for your question, I'm not sure what's wrong with your query, but note that you don't need to ask the database to do the work. `now` is a constant. `60` is a constant. The only value you need to get from the database is `created_at`, the rest you can do in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models import F

Review.objects.annotate(time_since_creation=timezone.now()-F('created_at')).order_by('-time_since_creation')
```

Wasn't sure which way you wanted to order by but you can play around with the minus sign to get what you want.